# Detect the Encoding of Spreadsheet Files with Python

Tags: python, excel, unicode, encoding

What is the most reliable way to detect the encoding of text in a spreadsheet file? I am using Python 3.8 to detect the encoding of CSV and Microsoft Excel (.xlsx and .xls) files that contain text from Western European, Central European, and Eastern European languages (e.g. English, Spanish, French, Polish, Russian, Ukrainian, etc.).
Each spreadsheet file will only contain text written in only one of those language.

I've  tried using Beautiful Soup's UnicodeDammit libary to detect the encoding of a text and it works most of the time, and bs4.UnicodeDammit library is more accurate than the chardet library (https://pypi.org/project/chardet/). However, UnicodeDammit fails to detect some encodings such as Windows 1250:

```
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit
text = 'Wrocław' 
win_1250_bytes = text.encode('windows-1250') #Polish text encoded to win-1250
print(win_1250_bytes)
b'Wroc\xb3aw'
print(UnicodeDammit(win_1250_bytes).original_encoding)
iso-8859-1
```

It seems that CSV files can be saved with an explicit encoding (such as windows-1250, etc.) but Microsoft Excel spreadsheets are limited in the encodings it can save as? It seems that MS-Excel file are saved as utf-8 by default and there's no way to save to a non-UTF8 encoding in MS-Excel.

I've written a spreadsheet class in my code but am unsure about how to accurately detect the encoding of the text in CSV and Excel files:

```
import pandas as pd
from os import path
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit


class SpreadsheetFile:

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        if path.isfile(file_path) and file_path.lower().endswith('.csv'):
            self._dataframe = pd.read_csv(file_path)
   self._encoding = self.get_file_encoding(file_path)

        elif path.isfile(file_path) and (file_path.lower().endswith('.xls') or file_path.lower().endswith('.xlsx')):
            self._dataframe = pd.read_excel(file_path)
   self._encoding = self.get_file_encoding(file_path)


    def get_file_encoding(self, file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            content = f.read()
            return UnicodeDammit(content).original_encoding
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: There's no way to accurately detect encodings. Encodings are typically specified somewhere – eg. in the headers of an HTTP request/response, in the metadata of structured files like XML, or in the specs like for JSON (and you presume for XLS – this can certainly be verified). But if it's not specified, then you're down to guessing (eg. through a library). And guessing is guessing – it's by definition not (100%) accurate.

Comment: `UnicodeDammit(win_1250_bytes).tried_encodings` says `[('utf-8', 'strict'), ('windows-1252', 'strict')]`